# entity framework "composite" property?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4.1, code first and want a property on a customer entity built up of a constant string value and the customerId zero padded to act as a customer reference.

I might be being a bit daft but am struggling to work out how I can achieve this without 
A) having to savechanges twice, once to get the Id then set my reference and save again
B) having a partial Customer class that simply provides a getter returning constant + CustomerId.Tostring("000000")

Is this "doable" with code first?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the database I would make a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this. Thus, you leave it to the database to generate a reference value and it will also be available to other consumers of the database (if any).

Your `Customer` class will have a property like `CustomerReference` (string) that maps to the computed column and that is [configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829109%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to have `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` which will cause EF to read the value after inserting an object.

Comment: This sounds like a truly beautiful approach. Cheers